# Can my giants and humans coexist?

Tags: society, creature-design, technological-development, fantasy-races

[*See my earlier question for the Giants version !*](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/88526/jobs-for-giants-in-modern-society)

> *How quickly the tide turns...*

In my world, Humans are a thing. These little people just appeared, I hope they can be friends with us, giants. Anyhow they are gonna have an influence of some kind.

First here are some specs about these little people who call themselves "humans".

- They are small and weak. Probably because they don't eat as much as us.
- They are smart and have great ideas. I hope they wont try to trick us.
- They eat about 10 times less than us giants.
- They live up to 80 years, at least that's what they told us.
- They are about 10'000'000. They appeared 2 year ago, without any equipment, just their tiny clothes. We helped them survive out of curiosity. They said they were from a place called "Russia"
- They have a tendency of getting eaten by the native megafauna.

Oh, I should tell you about my world too.

- Our world is about twice the size of the human's planet. They told us something about how "Gravity isn't different here".  I wonder what that means.
- Animals and plants here are the same as they were in the "[Pleistocene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pleistocene)". According to human's scientists.
- There are about 500'000'000 giants in the world. Weird, [it seems 5'000'000 of them are missing.](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/88526/jobs-for-giants-in-modern-society)
- We, Giants, have a level of technology equal to the "Early Middle-ages (5th to 8th century)". Another fancy human term.

Humans are very smart and started to organize themselves already. I wonder how it will work out. But I have a few concerns that maybe some of my smart giant brothers can answer:

1. Can humans survive in that scenery?
2. Would the humans be of use to the giants?
3. Can humans be a threat to giants? If so, in what time frame?

Comment: Questions asking "How would X alter society?" are often closed as too broad.

Comment: @sphennings Thanks for the warning I guess. ^^

Comment: There are currently three votes to close your question as too broad. It's highly likely that unless you edit your question it will be put on hold. If you edited your question to narrow it's scope it could remain open or be reopened.

Comment: @sphennings Oh I see. That I shall do. Thanks.

Comment: You might want to consider changing the title a bit in that case. It already says that you are interested in the impact on society. Maybe you could change it to something like "What would be the problems Giants would have to face if suddenly normal humans appeared?"

Comment: @Secespitus True, true. I'll take your word for it.

Answer (score 3):

#### They can coexist and it will give your Giants rapid technological development - for some time

The *humans* will help your society with a spurt of technological development. They are very intelligent and know a lot of difficult stuff that you do not yet understand.

The only problem is that they only have a lifetime for this. This is not so much when you want to bring a whole society to a different technological level, because probably not everyone of your kind will be as trusting as you are. Some will fear those *humans* and try to kill them. Some *humans* will get eaten by the Megafauna as you already mentioned. If you are lucky they will resist most of your diseases, but even a single disease that you have and they don't could kill all of them if they are in one place.

And even if the ones survive that could help you with your current technological level they will die after a few dozen years or so from old age. That is, if you give them everything they need to live a comfortable life without having to actually work. After all they can't really lift anything with their tiny arms. They are not very useful in your current situation, except for talking about fancy stuff and talking about things that sound so surreal that you can't be sure whether they are telling the truth or just trying to get a free meal while not being eaten themselves.

If you can breed those *humans* that are not killed by diseases and the supposedly *hard* life that you are currently living they will soon forget most of what the first generation knew. After all there is currently no infrastructure to help them teach each other and they are always talking about their *books* and *computers* where they stored all those information. But they don't have any access to that anymore.

They will soon be at our level. If we can breed them we will be faster in our technological development. They are useful because they are intelligent and very creative. They don't eat much, so it's not really a problem to hold a couple of them as pets and *engineers* as some of them like to call themselves.

They are no danger as they don't have access to any weapons and can't use our wepaons. They are helpless. And by integrating them into our society we can control their access to our weapons. They are only a few and if we are careful about what they are developing there shouldn't be a problem.

If we are not careful about what they are developing they might be a problem. The current generation is afraid of the giants and might try to take advantage of their inferior intellect if they ever get the chance. You should try to make them a separate lower class with restricted access to resources, but make them feel special by caring for their needs as best as you can. This way they won't feel like a lower class. Just be sure not to let them change your politics too much. They like to talk a lot about complicated stuff, but much of it has to do with killing each other and other species. That's not something you want for your Giant society.

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid they are a threat to us Giant, my dear.

I have got one of them human reading me one of their books, I think they call it "*History*", and they insist it is real, not just lullabies or fairy tales.

Well, according to this "*History*", they are like mold in our lovely jam: they spread all around until there is no room left, they are very prone to slaughter and kill those who are different to them to be sure to get more and more of all they want (and they have also these "*religion differences*", "*political differences*", "*skin color differences*", "*unfolding toilet paper difference*" which I didn't have enough smoky herb to fully swallow in my mind, but I got that they take them seriously enough to kill in their name).

As long as my mind goes, I think we Giant are different to them, so I am afraid they will soon put us in their "*History*", too.

You see, they are starting to build bigger weapons and asking our ores to do it, "to get rid of the big animals", they say. But a blade is a blade, and you also heard that some of them are not happy when we are around them.

Answer (score 2):

*NOTE: I apologise in advance for this. I enjoyed myself so much I got carried away. TLDR: No, I think that they will not be able to share a world in peace.*

**These humans are a giant threat to Giant Society**

These small creatures are an immediate threat to giant society! Do not trust them!

**Intellect**

The humans are cunning and many giants do not trust them! The humans will quickly learn how to exploit their protectors' stupidity. They will prove their intellect by creating things no giant has ever done, and quickly rise to be superior in literature, music, arts, architecture, design, language, and agriculture.

The humans say they remember things from where they came from; they begin to talk about "Machinery" and "Steam Power".

They will introduce new farming methods such as crop rotation, and the giants will hail them for their "revolutionary" ideas on steam power. Machinery will quickly develop, leading to factories and a busy industry, all created by these humans.

Giants, unable to comprehend how any of it works, will simply accept their role as factory workers or heavy lifters within this newfangled "modern age".

**Discontent**

The elder giants are now worried. Despite all our notions of "Innovation" and "Discovery", the majority often fear new things (especially the older generations). Those elders who have power within the giant society do not trust the humans! They call for the giants to not work for them. Meanwhile, the younger giants are gaining money, resources, and all sorts of new goodies from the results of the humans' creations. They side with the humans, their saviours.

Giant society is being split into two and there is a lot of unease among the people.

**War, huh?**

The giants know that they are stronger than the humans, despite their outward appearance of being able to manipulate the land. The elders tell their people about how the factories are putting smoke into the air, and forests are retreating and being burnt down to fuel these places of hard labour, where the human owners reap the greatest rewards and give the scraps to the giant workers.

Some giants, seeking material wealth or power will side with the humans, revelling in their creations such as "Trains", "Cannons", and the recently created "Automobile". Black powder, used in the mines for breaking stones that even the giants cannot crack, is used in their new "Musket" to hit things from far away!

The elder giants mass a group who say that they should never have taken the humans into their world, for they have brought destruction of the trees and pollution of the air. They use their dark powers to make their automobiles move, and since none of the giants know how they work they begin to beleive them.

They seek to destroy the humans' creations.

**What is it good for?**

They say that the giants who side with the humans are treacherous, greedy, and power-driven. The humans do not fear the giants though, since they can hit from further distances with weapons far outweighing the giants' bows and ballistae. The giants specialise in melee combat, but the humans have surpassed that level. After the first strike, the elders declare "war". The humans, on the other hand, declare "extermination".

The humans have faster boats, and their navies can destroy towns and villages on the coast with their explosives. They can take down stone outposts that have stood for years with their iron shells.

Their "Automobiles" can outrun any giant or their mount, without halting. They can carry heavy guns, or food supplies, or anything they want.

The giants never get close enough to use their sword, axe, and hammer skills. The giant archers have better luck, but do nowhere near as much damage.

Some giants who joined the humans see the destruction of their people and plead for mercy. Some even rebel. The humans were clever enough to see this coming though, and have systems in place to deal with them.

Destruction continues until the giants surrender. The humans survey their work, and what is left?

**Absolutely nothing**

The humans have brought invention and intellect to the giants' world but it came with a price. The giant clans had always fought amongst themselves, but their forms of combat never left the battlefield. The price for new inventions is that they can cause more destruction. The humans' inventions have lain waste to everything, simply to defend themselves.

Giant populations are down, and human populations have grown. The giants go into hiding in the mountains and the humans spread over time to claim most of the lands. The giants fade in the humans' memory. For the giants, they remember. They tell stories of the destruction of their world. They cannot leave their harsh climates without risking discovery. They live in fear, but for generations to come, they will not know what that fear is.

Perhaps one day they will resurface in desperation to find food. They will go forth in their small numbers to find an advanced race, with "Roads" and "Computers" and "Aeroplanes", and will [search for jobs in order to feed their families](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/88526/jobs-for-giants-in-modern-society).

Comment: And all the things they create have little parts that hold them together that require such small tools that we would never be able to fix them.  I thinks, the "littles" are making sure we can never get rid of them.